# Simulating Charged Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, proteus, simulation, multisim

Is there any in built mechanism to simulate a charged capacitor in simulation software like Multisim or Proteus?

If not, is there any alternative method for simulation of partially charged Capacitors?

Comment: why the minus vote? isn't this just a question of whether you can specify initial state of energy-storing components?

Comment: Not sure about those programs, but in some programs you can define a floating voltage source.  Perhaps putting one of those in series with the cap will have the desired effect?

Comment: At least on Proteus 8.1 version, there's a real capacitor model named as REALCAP in generic capacitors section which you can set its initial voltage charge.

Answer (score 3):

You can set initial conditions with SPICE directives

See  here:
http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/spice.overview.html#Initial